# How to use generic typing for acessing objects

Tags: typescript, oop

I need a way to access obj via class.
I want to use generic typing for that.

The problem is that inside the class I get an error - it is not possible to check if this.locators contain input field.

```
 type '{ form1: { item2: { checkbox: string; input: string; }; }; form2: { item1: { checkbox: string; }; }; }[T][F]' is not assignable to type 'object'.
  Type '{ form1: { item2: { checkbox: string; input: string; }; }; form2: { item1: { checkbox: string; }; }; }[T][keyof { form1: { item2: { checkbox: string; input: string; }; }; form2: { item1: { checkbox: string; }; }; }[T]]' is not assignable to type 'object'.
    Type '{ form1: { item2: { checkbox: string; input: string; }; }; form2: { item1: { checkbox: string; }; }; }[T][string] | { form1: { item2: { checkbox: string; input: string; }; }; form2: { item1: { checkbox: string; }; }; }[T][number] | { ...; }[T][symbol]' is not assignable to type 'object'.
      Type '{ form1: { item2: { checkbox: string; input: string; }; }; form2: { item1: { checkbox: string; }; }; }[T][string]' is not assignable to type 'object'
```

How to resolve it? I want to mention that type must be infered from the `const obj` I do not want to define any interface/type.

```
const obj = {
    form1: {
        item2: {
            checkbox: 'checkbox',
            input: 'input',
        }
    },
    form2: {
        item1: {
            checkbox: 'busin'
        }
    }
};

type ObjType = typeof obj;
type ProgramKeys = keyof ObjType;
type FormKeys<T extends ProgramKeys> = keyof ObjType[T];



class CheckboxFormOne<T extends ProgramKeys, F extends FormKeys<T>> {
    locators:  ObjType[T][F];

    constructor(public program: T, public form: F) {
        this.locators = obj[program][form];
    }


    fillInput(input: keyof typeof obj[T][F]) {  
        if ('input' in this.locators && typeof this.locators[input] === 'string') {
            this.locators.input
        }
    }
}
new CheckboxFormOne('form1', 'item2').fillInput('input')
```

Comment: • What's UploadForm? Is it necessary for the question? If not, please [edit] to remove it. • Please [edit] to [replace/supplement images of your IDE with plaintext](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) and make sure any error is written out as plaintext as well.

Comment: (see prev comment) Once you fix those, this looks like an instance of [ms/TS#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760) where doubly indexed generics lose their constraints, and you need to work around it, by re-constraining to an `object` type somewhere, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLOYKN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, it addresses the question.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer. Would you please do the [edit] to replace the image with text and write out the error as text as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug or limitation with TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760). When you start doing multiple [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), the compiler will tend to lose track of generic [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) and ends up widening them to something that causes errors.  Until and unless this is addressed (and it seems unlikely, or at least there's no indication that it's being worked on) you will need to work around it.

Generally when you have a type `X` that you know is assignable to a type `Y` but the compiler doesn't know this, you can often use the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `X & Y` in place of `X`.  If you're right about the assignability, then `X & Y` will end up being equivalent to `X` (there are some exceptions with function types but that's not directly relevant here). But the compiler will accept that `X & Y` is assignable to `Y` by the definition of the intersection.

One workaround then is to intersect `ObjType[PK][FK]` with `object` so that TypeScript will let you use [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
class CheckboxFormOne<PK extends ProgramKeys, FK extends FormKeys<PK>> {
    locators: object & ObjType[PK][FK]; // constrain to object

    constructor(public program: PK, public form: FK) {
        this.locators = obj[program][form]! // assert non-nullish
    }

    fillInput(input: keyof typeof obj[PK][FK]) {
        if ('input' in this.locators && typeof this.locators[input] === 'string') {
            this.locators.input
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the compiler still can't figure out that `obj[program][form]` is non-nullish, so I use a [non-null assertion operator (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) there.

Or you could do more runtime checks to just convince TS that `this.locations` is an object:

```
class CheckboxFormOne<PK extends ProgramKeys, FK extends FormKeys<PK>> {
    locators: ObjType[PK][FK];

    constructor(public program: PK, public form: FK) {
        this.locators = obj[program][form];
    }

    fillInput(input: keyof typeof obj[PK][FK]) {
        // do extra runtime tests
        if (this.locators && typeof this.locators === "object" &&
            'input' in this.locators && typeof this.locators[input] === 'string') {
            this.locators.input
        }
    }
}
```

Neither one of those is particularly great, and there are other also not-great approaches, but the point is you'll need to work around it somehow.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-b1rWoFtUCg0GIJVpCmIywnTT2W3arUO5wErP443oAQB3GCfKQuVH-BjV-WkORuGwsGeWpOp9PVocz0Lx-bEQ7HU4wC6EK43MbMCazx+nuXyHl0x5AgiYITGq0wwhAcJMoMiLIh0XQIVBmImjQi5EpQKxrAwdLbCWOyioo4o8lKdpyqoCpKiqcFlJq5TavRur4F0lBMrOFY4GaFq9rabaOkgzrMcQ7pdOR66hHOd5PGm2aZumlCLI0XaCiRDJMlsfH8eyMCjCAKE8iUMCSmAUC0O+-KHFAECrrgtBVoJzZ9ku7adkkmkLp5oljjAABEpLksF3nOZwNbpmI9aNkJeH2t5-K+d2iUBQOQ4jmO46TmA04GfxuDucJ-bLumUUwBunA1dVW4MLu+7OCIR4AqeXTnnCNaMNehq3smSkPjF2bPoEQA)